# Update last row in mysql from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms

I try to update the last row in a table with user's input email 
the email column is optional

**Html**:

I used first form to return item details and update Mysql table - works fine,
I put second input for email updates, if a user wants to receive updates

```
form action="actionemail.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkMail(this);">...</form>
```

The checkMail doesn't work

**Javascript**

```
function checkMail(){
 if ( theForm.checkbox.checked == false) 
 {
       alert('Did not check box');
       return false;
 } else {  
     return 'Thank you we will update you';
 }
}
```

I want to update the last row in table with the user email input to Email column, So I have two calls for server the form works fine

I used this code in php script
(details are deleted)

```
<?
 php $servername = "localhost"; $username = ""; $password = "";
 $dbname ="";

 $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

 if (!$conn) {
   die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error()); }

  //$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');  //$IP = "$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]";

 $email = $_POST["email"];

//$sql = "INSERT INTO enterlog (ItemCode, EnterDate, IPAddress, Email) VALUES ('$itemCode', '$time', '$IP', '$email')";


  $last = "SELECT MAX(LogID) FROM enterlog";

  $sql_update = "UPDATE enterlog SET Email='.$email.' WHERE logid=$last";

   if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql_update)) {
      echo "<h5>thank you"; } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn); }

    mysqli_close($conn); 
?>
```

I get this error (new):

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT MAX(LogID) FROM enterlog' at line 1

I manage to add new line to table, I can't add the email optional input to the last line.

So what's wrong?

Comment: what is error you are getting  ??

Comment: did you echo $email? Is there a value, or is it `NULL` by any chance?

Comment: @PrashantSrivastav I get "Error:" > can't update the Table,

Comment: @Jeff when echo it shows with error, so form works..

Comment: if (mysqli_query($conn, $row)) 
$row is not defined.

Comment: @IseNgaRt you're right I changed it again, now I get syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change your php file starting from

```
<?
 php
```

to `<?php`

and Change the following line

```
$last = "SELECT MAX(LogID) FROM enterlog";
$sql_update = "UPDATE enterlog SET Email='.$Email.' WHERE logid=$last";
```

to:

```
$last = "SELECT MAX(LogID) AS last_id FROM enterlog";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $last);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$last_id = $row['last_id'];

$sql_update = "UPDATE enterlog SET Email='$Email' WHERE logid='$last_id'";
```

Comment: IT Works! also needed to fix Email to email. 
could you explain more your code

Comment: how do I set the success message to show on same page other then a new page?

Comment: Submit the page in same page `action="Your_Current_Page"` and set the update code at the top of the page.

Comment: I understand, but it returns on top of the page, I prefer to use jacascript so the return shown under the form in a <div>

Comment: Store your message in a `variable` and use javascript command `<script>alert(<?php echo $your_var_name; ?>);</script>`

Comment: how can I avoid the refresh of the page when submitting the form?

Comment: showed the message using <div id="welcomeDiv" style="display:none;"> <  function showMsg() </div>
 document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = 'block';